# Node.Js seems to be ignoring the await keyword on random executions

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I have an asynchronous function:

```
async function getLeads(page) {
    return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        while (true) {
            await page.waitFor(1000);
            const content = await page.content();
            const contentArr = content.split('<div');
            const matchedValue = contentArr.filter(
                //@ts-ignore
                arr =>
                    arr.search('move;">Remaining records in active lists</div>') !== -1
            )[0];
            const index = contentArr.indexOf(matchedValue) + 3;
            const value = contentArr[index];
            const totalLeads = value.split('>')[1].split('<')[0];
            if (totalLeads === '-') {
                console.log('Leads not ready trying again...');
            } else {
                resolve(totalLeads);
            }
        }
        reject();
    });
}
```

This function is within a more complicated function however I will simplify:

```
async function scrape() {
    console.log('Starting Lead Wait...');
    const totalLeads = await getLeads(page);
    console.log(`Total Number of leads: ${totalLeads}`);
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    console.log('Browser closed!');
}
```

Sometimes this works as expected and the output is:

```
Loading page...
Logging in...
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
Total Number of leads: 323
Browser closed!
```

Other times it seems to ignore the await keyword and print:

```
Loading page...
Logging in...
Starting Lead Wait...
Total Number of leads: 
Browser closed!
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
Leads not ready trying again...
```

Any idea why this inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a closer look at the function execution, 'totalLeads' on certain cases resolves to undefined resolving the promise with no value, since there is no break in the while loop the while loop continues to execute code even though the promise has been resolved. Fixed with 2 changes:

the if is now an else if() and tests for a more specific case.
added a break after the resolve.

I do have a question though, How does the while loop keep executing even though the function that contains it had returned?